# Shaders and textures lifecycle in cocos3d

Tags: ios, opengl-es, cocos3d

I'm not sure how to manage (custom) shaders and textures. I'm using multiple textures and some out-of-the-box shaders and one custom shader. I'm really struggling to get them running and not reloading each time I'm removing and adding node to the scene.

Now I'm struggling with scenario:

1. (pre)load textures and shaders, do some caching.
2. Wait some time with empty scene for user interaction
3. Add some objects to screen.
4. BUM, still black screen

Scenario works if I add objects right away when scene is created. But that's not the point, let's not focus on that scenario. I'm totally lost when and where should I load shaders, textures, how to force them to stay loaded in memory, how should I work with threads (which of these steps can be done in backgrounder, which should be in the main thread), how to use preloading, and so on. So the questions are:

1. When (and which lifecycle method should I use) to preload shaders
2. How to preload shaders and textures to force them to stay loaded in memory (also which lifecycle methods should I use)
3. How should I load shaders and textures later in the scene (i mean - in which methods should I do that)
4. How should I use texture and shader caches
5. How should I select textures and shaders for my nodes (in which methods should i do that, and should I keep reference for my custom shader or can I use shader cache, if so, how and when should I fetch a shader for my node)

Currently I even wrote my ShaderMatcher, so that it's selecting my shader for my nodes. But during runtime in logs I can see that ALL the shaders (including my custom one) are loaded and released. I'm totally confused.

I'm not using any models, pods or so, only generated terrain, custom meshes and parametric ones.

Answer (score 0):

I've answered your same post to the Cocos3D forum [there](http://forum.cocos2d-swift.org/t/shaders-and-textures-lifecycle-in-cocos3d/15042/2).